# How to know statistical data on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have deployed an application on Google App Engine; I would like to see a statistical view on how many people visit my site and from where in the world do they access, is it possible? What do I need to do to have those results?

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/analytics/) for that. It's easy to do - you just need to subscribe from the analytics website with your google account and drop hooks on the pages you want to collect statistics for. Have a look at the analytics link, they have pretty straightforward tutorials.

On the other end, If you're looking for load information (how much cpu on google servers your app is using, throughput, etc.) then you have to look at the app engine dashboard for your app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, thank John, I played around with the dashboard but it does not give what I want to know. I'll take a look at the Google Analytics ;)

Answer (score 0):

Logs filter take a regex that eases client load compared to google analytics.